# viewPager swipe based on certain condition

Tags: android, android-viewpager, swipe

I have a viewPager that swipes 5 or more pages. Some of the pages contain form input fields. Based on the input value swipe is either be enabled or disabled.
For example: if the page contains checkbox and it is mandatory field to be checked. If checked only then swipe should work otherwise stay on the same page.

Answer (score 1):

You can extend the viewpager class to create your custom viewpager implementation. In that class you need to override "canScrollHorizontally" method as per your needs to return true or false

```
    public class LockableViewPager extends ViewPager {

        private boolean swipeLocked;

        public LockableViewPager(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }

        public LockableViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
        }

        public boolean getSwipeLocked() {
            return swipeLocked;
        }

        public void setSwipeLocked(boolean swipeLocked) {
            this.swipeLocked = swipeLocked;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            return !swipeLocked && super.onTouchEvent(event);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            return !swipeLocked && super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean canScrollHorizontally(int direction) {
            //control this method based on your logic
            return !swipeLocked && super.canScrollHorizontally(direction);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Can you please give an example of calling this method in activity?